# Modify environment variables or configurations for a module on an IoT Edge deployment

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

Is there a quick way to modify environment variables, or configurations (that is accessible) for a module in IoT Edge?
Once a deployment is created, the environment variables become read only.
What would be the best practice of maintaining a modifiable set of configurations, so I can rather easily change them on the fly, and have the module be able to access them?

On Azure Cloud Services, for example, there are web configurations that are editable and would restart the service so they would kick in (since they are accessible to the service). I am looking for the same kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the module's device twin in the portal and deploy it. The module should be informed of the update. Alternatively you could send your module a direct message.

Comment: Sending a direct message was the way I was thinking of going with, however it is not as "simple", quick and straight forward as modifying settings (and it relies on code). I will check the twin option though, thanks!

Comment: I think you only need to modify the desired properties in the twin module and that should be it.

Answer (score 0):

Screen shots on how to update the IOT Edge Module's Environment Variables.
Note, I am using the VisionAI Kit camera in this example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Screen shots on how to update the IOT Edge Module's Environment Variables.
Note, I am using the VisionAI Kit camera in this example.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is Cloud To Device (C2D)communication. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-c2d-guidance) for details.

Out of all, the best match is Module Twin Desired Property update.
You can easily create handlers for desired property updates in your edge module implementation and run custom logic based on the changes in desired properties.
For C#, the handler code would go like -

`await ioTHubModuleClient.SetDesiredPropertyUpdateCallbackAsync(OnDesiredPropertiesUpdate, null);`

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-csharp-module?view=iotedge-2018-06#update-the-module-with-custom-code) would be a great read on it.

P.S : *Environment Variables are designed to be read-only after deployment. It should only have configurations that are deployment specific and do not change post deployment.*